# WP7 Image Uri as StaticResource

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 app and I'm trying to move some common elements into resource files.

Text and Styles work fine but I'm struggling to find the right way to partition out Uri's.

This is a code sample I'm trying to get to work.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="{StaticResource MenuButton1}" Text="Button1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="{StaticResource MenuButton2}" Text="Button2"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

I have made a AppImages.xaml file and here is the code from there;

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="MenuButton1">/Images/button1.png</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="MenuButton2">/Images/button2.png</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It's clear that I can't just use a string but I don't know what I should use.

I am new to WP7 development so if I'm doing something obviously wrong please let me know.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: It is not bad to hard-code those string into XAML  <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/button2.png" Text="Button 1"/>

Comment: But if my app has 10 pages. I'll hard code them in every time. Doesn't seem right. Is there not a better way? Whats best practice?

Comment: I would step back myself. IMO 10 pages is too many (I don't know the app, but that's my guess). Have you thought of Panorama or Pivot control? Does each page have completely different ApplicationBar? For me is annoying to press back button 5 times to get back to some page and wait for all animations to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing I'd guess that you're trying to use a string to a parameter which takes a URI. You could try adding a converter to get it into the right type. The framework would normally make the conversion automatically.

Does the debug output show any (binding) errors?

Rather than defining resources this way you could create a class which exposes static properties for each URI. See example on my blog at:  http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2011/03/binding-to-static-classes-in-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try to store the `Uri` itself as a resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System">
    <sys:Uri x:Key="MenuButton1">/Images/button1.png</sys:Uri>
    <sys:Uri x:Key="MenuButton2">/Images/button2.png</sys:Uri>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note `assembly=System` in the `xmlns:sys` namespace declaration. Also, when you type `<sys:` in the Visual Studio editor, `Uri` won't be shown in the IntelliSense list, but it seems perfectly fine to use it in XAML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information about the validity of using <sys:Uri> even when Visual Studio does now show it. It was really helpful.