# Uri in Resource dictionary in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend, resourcedictionary

I have defined one resource dictionary in my wp7 project in themes folder with name of darktheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System">

    <sys:Uri x:Key="AppBarSettingsImage">/Images/dark/Settings.png</sys:Uri>
    <sys:Uri x:Key="AppBarTimingsImage" >/Images/dark/Timings.png</sys:Uri>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I am calling this is my App.xaml like this

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DarkTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I did all images as build action Content and CopyIfnewer And for my theme build action as page

Once I run my project it thorows the unhandled exception for loading the resource dictionary. But When I comment out this code in my theme (resource dictionary) it start working.

```
<sys:Uri x:Key="AppBarSettingsImage">/Images/dark/Settings.png</sys:Uri>
<sys:Uri x:Key="AppBarTimingsImage" >/Images/dark/Timings.png</sys:Uri>
```

Actually I am setting these uri for setting my appbar iconuri property to set with my these static resources. As discussed here 
[WP7 Image Uri as StaticResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470941/wp7-image-uri-as-staticresource)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot bind (use staticresource) to ApplicationBarIconButton. It is not a Silverlight control, it is just a wrapper object for a low level interop with the Windows Phone 7 OS. So it cannot be databinded.

I could suggest two options to do that.

First and the easyer one: You can manipulate it from code-behind. Here you can acces your resourcedictionary too, it is just a working sample from me (with the hard-coded string).

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //this.AppBarButton1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/dark/Timing.png"); //WRONG NullReferenceException
    var button1 = this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
    button1.IconUri = new Uri(@"./Images/dark/Timing.png", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

The second one requeres more coding: 
You could implement your own ApplicationBarIconButton. You need to derive from **ApplicationBarMenuItem** and implement **Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IApplicationBarIconButton**.
After that you can add a DependencyProperty to your own control like:

```
public Uri IconUri
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(IconUriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconUriProperty, value); }
    }

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconUri.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconUriProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IconUri",
        typeof(Uri),
        typeof(ApplicationBarIconButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(Uri), (d, e) => ((ApplicationBarIconButton)d).IconUriChanged((Uri)e.NewValue)));

private void IconUriChanged(Uri iconUri)
{
    var button = SysAppBarMenuItem as Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IApplicationBarIconButton;
    button.IconUri = iconUri;
}
```

I hope it could help you.